# When should I use php-fpm, php-cli, php-mbstring with phpmyadmin/nginx config

Tags: php, nginx, phpmyadmin

After following many tutorials on nginx for a basic phpymadmin setup, I have concluded that I am confused as to why certain  tutorials recommend certain php modules while others do not.

My working configuration is with php7-fpm, php7-mbstring.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name name ip;

    root /var/www/html/phpmyadmin;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ ^/(.*\.php)$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Most tutorials suggest php-fpm, php-cli, and another module.
Do I need these, and why would I need these modules for phpmyadmin?

Is my nginx configuration the correct way to have it function properly (not the most secure), or should I add any other locations/modules to my nginx configuration such as,

```
location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                       root /path/;
```

Comment: `php-cli` is for executing PHP via the command line. `php-mbstring` is a PHP extension for working with strings encoded in a multibyte encoding. See also, https://serverfault.com/questions/645755/differences-and-dis-advanages-between-fast-cgi-cgi-mod-php-suphp-php-fpm